# Surface area under a curve (made by incomplete sprial pattern) on a sphere

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I have an incomplete spiral pattern (as shown)  on a sphere of radius R. I want to find the area under the curve made by the highest points of the incomplete spiral.
[Image showing the incomplete spiral pattern on a sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob9Hv.png)

I have tried solving this in these ways:

1. Thinking about how one finds an area under a curve on a circle. One would make slices of some width w and find the height value of Y in each bin and just multiply Y*w to get that bin contribution. Add all the contributions and get the area under the curve. I am not able to translate this idea for a sphere, how to bin this?

2. Another way is to consider a disk(in Y-Z plane) of width w, some r distance from the center of the sphere. Now depending on this r, the number of points lying on that disk will vary. One can find the center of this disk and find at which angles are the "top" two points are, find the arc length, and multiply with width w. Do all the disks and add them and that's your area under the curve. This didn't work because there are multiple(which are not the part of the topmost curve) contributing to the area, which is wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

These are the coordinates in (x,y,z) format: https://pastebin.com/Att1Ep1r

P.S.: This is my first time asking questions on stack exchange. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: If projected arc in horizontal plane = ds, you want $ \int z \;ds ?$ How were the given points obtatined ? Loxodromic rhumb lines?

Comment: @Narasimham I don't know to find the projected arc made by only the topmost points of the incomplete spiral. Also, if we project it wouldn't it lose the sphere, to begin with.
These lines I got from the Fibonnachi sphere, we would like to obtain how much area/volume of the sphere is covered by a sheet. These results are from a simulation. Thus, I got these points which are covered, now I want to find how much of the surface area/volume these points contribute.

Comment: There is no curve in your question ! By the way, there is no reason to consider 3D points, work with the projection.